# ShuffleSplit equivalent in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sampling

What is the equivalent function of `sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit` that DOES guarantee that all folds will be different?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold . The whole list is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection)

Comment: I don't think there is a direct function for this, since they are *random* permutations after all. Though the docs do mention that it is very unlikely to have repeated folds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `KFold` guarantees that test indices won't overlap, it forces a relationship between no. of times to repeat the model evaluation and percentage of samples to use for test set  (i.e. `n_splits` and `test_size`). So if you want to use 10% data for testing, you'll have to train and evaluate your model 10 times- you can't repeat it 3 times for example, maybe to save time.

To combine the best of both worlds, one possible solution is to subclasses sklearn's `KFold`:

```
import itertools
class DSS(KFold):
    def __init__(self, n_repeat=5,test_size=.25, *, shuffle=True,
                 random_state=None):
        super().__init__(n_splits=int(1/test_size), shuffle=shuffle, 
                         random_state=random_state)
        self.n_repeat = n_repeat  

    def split(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
        gen_idx = super().split(X,y,groups)
        return itertools.islice(gen_idx,self.n_repeat) #Only keep first few index arrays
```

Example usage using Iris dataset:

```
cv = DSS(n_repeat=3,test_size=.1,shuffle=True)
for _,test_idx in cv.split(X,y): 
    print(test_idx )
```

Which outputs:

```
[ 18  20  25  27  48  50  67  95 110 113 124 125 137 145 147]
[ 29  36  56  58  60  63  68  77 100 106 117 121 129 134 141]
[  4  28  40  42  76  86  90  94  98 102 115 139 142 143 144]
```

You can of course use this `cv` in `cross_val_score` or `GridSearchCV` like normal `KFold`.